# Not able to generate HTML reports of code coverage from Clover Maven plugin

Tags: maven, code-coverage, clover

Trying to integrate Clover maven plugin to get the code coverage of my project.

After I build my project with `mvn clean install`, target folder looks like below

[image]

But I am looking for code coverage with HTML reports (Which will give us the code coverage with package wise, class wise views)

Will the line `<generateHtml>true</generateHtml>` does it ?, if yes, something wrong in my configuration.

How can I get HTML reports out of Clover maven plugin?

Below is the pom.xml code

```
<build> 
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <!-- <targetPercentage>80%</targetPercentage> -->
        <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
          <generatePdf>true</generatePdf>
          <generateXml>true</generateXml>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
             <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
               <goal>instrument</goal>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
          <generatePdf>true</generatePdf>
          <generateXml>true</generateXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Comment: Do you see test cases being executed as part of `mvn clean install` command?

Comment: Yes, Test cases got executed and build is success

Answer (score 1):

Please use `mvn clean install clover2:clover` command ad see if you get the html report generated in `target/site/clover/index.html` file.

The `clover2:clover` goal should instrument your test classes, execute the test cases and record the code coverage information.

Comment: `mvn clean install clover2:clover` command created index.html under `target/site/clover/clover/index.html`, but the html is empty. It has no information

Comment: Do I need to change something in the configuration ?

Comment: I used exactly your configuration and It worked fine for me. I was able to see the code coverage report in html format. Not sure, why your html is empty. I see two `clover` in the directory path you had mentioned. Is that a typo or you are looking at wrong path?

Comment: No, not typo the path is exactly same - `target/site/clover/clover/index.html`

Comment: Do you have `index.html` in `target/site/clover`?

Comment: No, Two clover folders are created, The path above is what I got

Comment: Do you have a pdf report and if yes, is that also empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148314/discussion-between-prathap-s-and-beginner).